# How to get environment variables in live Heroku dyno

Tags: bash, heroku

There is a `heroku config` command but that apparently just shows me what the current setting is. I want to confirm in a dyno what my application is actually seeing in the running environment.

I tried `heroku ps:exec -a <app> -d <dyno_instance> --ssh env`and this has some generic output (like `SHELL`, `PATH`, etc.) output but it doesn't show *any* env vars that I've configured (like my db strings, for example). I've also tried directly logging in (using `bash` instead of the `env` command) and poked around but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `heroku run env` instead.

According to the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#environment-variables): 
"The SSH session created by Heroku Exec will not have the config vars set as environment variables (i.e., env in a session will not list config vars set by `heroku config:set`)."

Answer (score 9):

`heroku run bash` does the similar to `heroku ps:exec` but has the config vars available.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is okay in most cases. `heroku run` will start a new dyno however, so it won't be enough you need to check the *actual* environment of an *running* dyno (let's say, purely hypothetically, that Heroku has an outage and can't start new dynos).

Here's one way to check the environment of a running dyno:

- Connect to the dyno: `heroku ps:exec --dyno <dyno name> --app <app name>`

  For example: `heroku ps:exec --dyno web.1 --app my-app`
- Get the pid of your server process (check your Procfile if you don't know). Let's say you're using `puma`:
  `ps aux | grep puma`

  The output might look something like this:

  ```
    u35949       4  2.9  0.3 673980 225384 ?       Sl   18:20   0:24 puma 3.12.6 (tcp://0.0.0.0:29326) [app]
    u35949      31  0.0  0.0  21476  2280 ?        S    18:20   0:00 bash --login -c bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
    u35949     126  0.1  0.3 1628536 229908 ?      Sl   18:23   0:00 puma: cluster worker 0: 4 [app]
    u35949     131  0.3  0.3 1628536 244664 ?      Sl   18:23   0:02 puma: cluster worker 1: 4 [app]
    u35949     196  0.0  0.0  14432  1044 pts/0    S+   18:34   0:00 grep puma
  ```

  Pick the first one (4, the first number in the second column, in this example)
- Now, you can get the environment of that process. Replace `<PID>` by the process id you just got, for example `4`:

  ```
  cat /proc/<PID>/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
  HEROKU_APP_NAME=my-app
  DYNO=web.1
  PWD=/app
  RACK_ENV=production
  DATABASE_URL=postgres://...
  ...
  ```

  The `tr` is there to make it easier to read, since the contents of `/proc/<pid>/environ` is zero-delimited.

Answer (score 0):

If your Heroku stack supports Node.js, then you can run a Node.js process on your Heroku app and print all (and not just the ones, that you configured) environment variables.

**Commands:**

1. `heroku run node --app your-heroku-app-name`
2. `console.log(process.env)`

Comment: `heroku run sh --app <name>` generally works as well, if `sh` is available but `node` is not. Then once connected, run `env`