# Heroku env variables $DATABASE_URL and $PORT not showing in dyno (heroku ps:exec)

Tags: docker, heroku, github-actions

I've created a docker image and published it to heroku. For it to work properly I need the `DATABASE_URL` env variable. Postgres is provisioned to the app, and I can `heroku config:get` the db URL just fine. Yet after all is done I `heroku ps:exec` into my app, type 'env' and there is no `$PORT` or `$DATABASE_URL`, meaning my app cant get the db string.

the steps I took:

**Github Action:**

```yaml
    - name: Build and deploy the Docker image
      env: 
        HEROKU_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}
        APP_NAME: myApp
      run: |
        export DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL --app ${{ env.APP_NAME }})
        docker login --username=_ --password=${{ env.HEROKU_API_KEY }} registry.heroku.com
        docker build --build-arg DATABASE_URL_ARG=$DATABASE_URL -t registry.heroku.com/${{ env.APP_NAME }}/web .
        docker push registry.heroku.com/${{ env.APP_NAME }}/web
```

**Dockerfile:**

```yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS publish
WORKDIR /src
ARG DATABASE_URL_ARG
ENV DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL_ARG
COPY . .
RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-ef && dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
ENV DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL_ARG
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/publish .
CMD DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL} dotnet app.dll
```

The build process is successful and the postgres db is seeded.
I don't know if the second ENV is needed, its there as an artifact of me trying to make something work.

***So the question is:*** where are the missing $PORT and $DATABASE_URL and how did I make them disappear?

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working, but it looks like you're trying to compile your `DATABASE_URL` into your Docker image at built time? That's not a very good idea, as it can change at any time. Why not just read it from the Heroku-provided environment variable at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, this was a mistake on my part specific to heroku usage.

After you push your docker image to heroku, you run `heroku container:release web`
I haven't done that, so I couldn't see my changes. As per documentation, $DATABASE_URL, and $PORT and added to the environment automatically and are available at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `heroku run bash` instead of `heroku ps:exec`**

Learned from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64951959/895245

I had setup `DATABASE_URL` with the PostgreSQL plugin `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`, and they show up under "Config Vars" on the web interface.

The app would run fine, the varaibles were present, but `heroku ps:exec` didn't have them, while `heroku run bash` did.

`heroku run bash` is mentioned at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos in a different context, so I think it should be fine to use it.

Comment: This solves my problem when deploying django and migrations are failing to access the postgreSQL database

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem is that [an ARG instruction goes out of scope at the end of the build stage where it was defined](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#scope), so you'd need the ARG defined in the second stage of the build, too:

```
# ...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
ARG DATABASE_URL_ARG
ENV DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL_ARG
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/publish .
CMD DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL} dotnet app.dll
```