# Heroku config vars/env vars not working (using node.js)

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-nodejs

The following setup does not work:

Setting a config var either via the dashboard or via

```
heroku config:set TESTVAR=123
```

using
heroku config
shows the variable is set.

But then logging into the container using

```
heroku ps:exec
```

and logging out the env vars should show the variable set via config:set but it does not:

```
node -e "console.log(process.env)"
```

Also using

```
export
```

does not show the environment variable.

I tried defining the variable in app.json but to no avail:

"env": {
"TESTVAR":{
"required": true
},

According to the documentation this should work but unfortunately it does not. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try heroku run env instead.

According to the documentation: "The SSH session created by Heroku Exec will not have the config vars set as environment variables (i.e., env in a session will not list config vars set by heroku config:set)."

see this for more information
[How to get environment variables in live Heroku dyno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119289/how-to-get-environment-variables-in-live-heroku-dyno)