# Heroku django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable

Tags: django, heroku, environment-variables, secret-key, django-commands

I am trying to run a django command on my heroku production server, but get the following error:

[image]

Note:  The same command works fine in my local dev environment.

I took the following steps:

1. ssh onto my django server:

   heroku ps:exec -a library-backend
2. I run my custom command:

   python manage.py test_command
3. Receive error above

My environment variables are set in my settings.py as follows:

```
import environ

# Setting environment variables
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))
environ.Env.read_env()
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
DATABASE_URL = env('DATABASE_URL')
```

My django app runs normally on the heroku server.  I am only getting this error when I try to run a custom django management command.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

For reference, the management command is specified in library/management/commands/test_command.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
      print("Testing management command")
```

Comment: How are you connecting to your heroku server? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119289/how-to-get-environment-variables-in-live-heroku-dyno

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#environment-variables) around `heroku ps:exec`:

> The SSH session created by Heroku Exec will not have the config vars set as environment variables (i.e., env in a session will not list config vars set by heroku config:set).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I figured this out at last with a hint in the right direction from the comment.  When you run:

```
heroku ps:exec -a <myapp>
```

Heroku will give you an ssh session with access to the files and folders, but won't set any of your environment variables (like SECRET_KEY or DATABASE_URL)

To get an ssh session with environment variables set, instead used:

```
heroku run bash -a <myapp>
```

Now you can run your django command and you won't get any ImproperlyConfigured errors.

Comment: `heroku run bash` will spin up a new dyno whereas `heroku ps:exec` will ssh into the running dyno. So this does not solve the problem